# Get max value from one array and find its location in another array

Tags: matlab, max

I'm new in Matlab but I really need to learn it. Hope it is very useful for my research. 
Now I'm facing the following problem.

I have two images (named A and B).  Both have 7 layers at the same dimension (4169,6289,7). First I'd like to find the layer that has a max value in A image and then look up a corresponding value in B image. For example: If fifth layer in A image has max value, I need the value of fifth layer in B image. 
I just wrote this code c=max(a,[],3) to find the layer with max value in A image but no idea to set up to get corresponding value in B image. can you help me for this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another take on it, that's a bit more memory efficient:

```
% get the indices in 3rd dimension for the max values
[~,I] = max(imgA,[],3)

% Collect all values through double loop
Bvals = arrayfun(@(y) ...
    arrayfun(@(x) imgB(x,y, I(x,y)), 1:size(imgA,1)), ...
    1:size(imgA,2), 'UniformOutput',false);

% reshape them so they correspond to the images' size again
Bvals = reshape([Bvals{:}], size(I))
```

Comment: @user1769107: Simple test run of both Andrey's `for`-loop and my solution gives: `for`-loop: 4.44 seconds. `arrayfun`: did not complete after 300 seconds. So: use for-loops :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the value of the max, you need the second argument, that is the index.

```
 [~,indexOfMax] = max(a,[],3); %#Get index of maximal element
 [g1,g2] = ndgrid( 1:size(a,1),1:size(a,2) );  %#Create all possible rows,cols
 linearIndex = sub2ind(size(a), g1(:),g2(:),index(:))  %#Linearize the index of the maximal elements
 value = b(linearIndex); %# Collect the maximal values from b
```

@RodyOldenhuis is right about the memory consumption. Here is a more memory-efficient, for loop approach: (Might or might not run faster, check yourself).

```
 vals = zeros(size(a(:,:,1)));
 [~,indexOfMax] = max(a,[],3);
 for i=1:size(a,1)
    for j=1:size(a,2)
        vals(i,j) = b(i,j, indexOfMax(i,j));
    end 
 end
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to me. You wrote in the last row 'collect the max values from B'. I just want the value (it can be lower than max) at the same layer of max value in A, not max value from B. In this case, this script will change or not? Thank you.

Comment: +1: my only problem with this is that with the dimensions the OP mentions, both `g1` and `g2` consume ~210MB of memory.

Comment: Dear Andrey, Now it works, but there is a thing in output. I just used it on example data set with the size of (2,2,2). The result is something like this (four separate outputs and value added one by one) vals =

    0.9575         0
         0         0


vals =

    0.9575    0.8003
         0         0


vals =

    0.9575    0.8003
    0.9649         0


vals =

    0.9575    0.8003
    0.9649    0.9706